# WFS layer invalid in standalone python script

Tags: pyqgis, wfs, standalone

I have a project in 3.10.11 (ltr) loading a layer from a Geoscience Australia WFS. https://services.ga.gov.au/site_1/services/Geomorphology_Scale_Guide_WM/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS

In the python plugin console this layer is valid and has correct extents.

[image: Image showing the python console testing is valid on WFS layer from Geoscience Australia]

When reading this project into a standalone python script the layer is no longer valid and the extent has changed, which appears to be an error in interpreting the geometry.

[image: command console showing python script testing layer for is valid and extents]

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from gdal import *
from osgeo import *
import qgis.utils
import os
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"]='C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.10\\share\\proj;C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.10\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\pyproj\\proj_dir\\share\\proj'
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.10\\apps", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read('D:\\temp\\Test.qgz')
layer = project.mapLayersByName('Guide 500K')[0]
layer.isValid()
layer.extent()
```

Comment: It looks like this might be a bug https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35354

Comment: Reported bug is for WMS not WFS, so may not be the same issue.  Also the issue reported seems to be about an invalid layer, but the service here doesn't seem to be invalid.

Comment: what if instead of '`Guide 500K` you use the full name of the featuretype `Geomorphology_Scale_Guide_WM:Guide_500K`

Comment: Hi @nmtoken thank you for pointing that out. This could possibly a separate bug to be reported. I tried your suggestion with the full name of the feature in both the typename and the layer name, which returned the same result.